# How to add an extra OR relation to a aot query linking a child parent and parent table

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

How to add an extra **OR relation to a aot query** linking a child parent (which is already linked to another parent table) with another parent table in the view's **init method in ax 2012** Please help me with a code.(Note: my issue how to give an or relation in aot query or relation between two parent tables(SecurityRole and SecuritySubRole) from the same child table securityRoleTaskGrant to fetch all the duties of security roles and securitysubroles in a single column of views.) using x++ coding

Thanks in advance,
Hari

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and take a look at [ask] to increase your chances to receive an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with expressions in the range of your query : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa893981.aspx.

Regards.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)